# How do I skip a previous commit when pushing to github?

Tags: git, android-studio, github, large-files

Working on a project in Android Studio, and I had a single file that I committed by mistake that was just over github's 100MB limit. I needed to modify that file anyway, so I did so, and it's about 50 MB now.

Problem is, when I try to push the new commit with the smaller file, it's also trying to push the old commit with the file that's too big. How can I skip the older commit and just push the new one?

Comment: You can't; see the duplicate.

Comment: (What you end up doing is removing one or more old commits, which also removes all the later commits after them, but make as many new *replacement* commits as you would like to have, instead of the old bad commits.)

Comment: try git rebase -i , then delete the commits